# How to improve the sub-query performance?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables, `users` and `games`. User can have many games. I need all the `users` who have `games`, along with their `games_hosted` count (`games` that have column `finished` to `true`.

P.S. I need all the data to load in a Admin Table. As there are too many games. I decided to paginate and limit data. But even limiting also the following query is taking the same time. How can I query this in a better way?

```
 select 
  distinct "uid", 
  "username", 
  (
    select 
      count(id) 
    from 
      games 
    where 
      state = 'finished' 
      and user_uid = users.uid
  ) as games_hosted 
from 
  "users" 
  inner join "games" on "games"."user_uid" = "users"."uid" 
where 
  "games"."state" in ('published', 'finished') 
  and "username" < 'HariShankar' 
order by 
  "username" desc 
limit 
  10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below- using `case when` expression

```
select "uid", "username", count(case when state = 'finished' then id end) as games_hosted 
from "users" inner join "games" 
on "games"."user_uid" = "users"."uid" 
where "games"."state" in ('published', 'finished') and "username" < 'HariShankar' 
group by "uid", "username"
order by "username" desc 
limit 10
```